# Simple Machine Learning example with handwritten digits does not work with conv2d and MaxPooling2D

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, max-pooling

I made an easy KI learning with tensorflow 2 with this code and everything works fine.

```
# Install TensorFlow
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
# Import matplotlib library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

#Import numpy
import numpy as np

#Dataset
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([

tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
print("Evaluation");
model.evaluate(x_test,  y_test)

plt.imshow(x_train[6], cmap="gray") # Import the image
plt.show() # Plot the image
predictions = model.predict([x_train]) # Make prediction
print("Vorhersage: ", np.argmax(predictions[6])) # Print out the number
print("Correct is: ", y_train[6])
```

My problem is how to add the detecting layers like Conv2d and MaxPooling2D. Where do I have to add this layers and does this influence my plotting and my predictions?

Answer (score 1):

Before passing input to Convolution2d and maxpool2d, input must have 4 dimensions.

x_train and x_test have shape 
[BatchSize, 28, 28] but it should be [BatchSize, 28, 28, 1].
So we are going to add channel dimension at last using `np.expand_dims()`

```
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1)  
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, -1)  

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same", input_shape=(None, 28, 28, 1)),
tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu"),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

Yes, It is going to influence your ploting and predictions.

Convolution layer uses less numbers of weights as compare to dense layer and then Maxpool will take features with only max values to make predictions. Which will reduce your feature because of this may be your accuracy will decrease.

Although, When we have images with large size like 500*500 then we have to apply Convolution and maxpool layers to reduce the features by selecting only important features.

If we apply flatten and dense function on input of 500*500 then program have to initialize large number of weights and you can get Out Of Memory error.